# I want to return only the odd numbers in a list

Tags: python, list

My issue here is that the code filters out the even numbers correctly which is what I want, however it stops at seven and doesn't display number 9  which is what I would expect it to do. I've tried going over my code but I can't seem to find the issue

```
def remove_even(numbers) :
    new_list = []
    for i in range(0,len(numbers)-1) :
        if i % 2 != 0 :
            new_list.append(i)
    return new_list
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
print(remove_even(l))
```

Comment: Please check before asking
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039374/how-can-i-return-the-odd-numbers-of-a-list-using-only-recursion-in-python

Comment: just use a list comprehension to create your list. `no_even = [x for x in range(n) if x % 2 != 0]`

Comment: You are looping through the indices, you need to replace `i` inside loop with `numbers[i]`.

Comment: Also see [Getting every odd variable in a list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780763/getting-every-odd-variable-in-a-list)

Comment: Using recursion in Python for this task is crazy. The only reason to do this recursively is as an exercise in recursion, and I suspect that the OP isn't quite at that stage yet.

Comment: @PM2Ring - Agreed... I'm not sure why OP accepted that as a duplicate.

Comment: Also note range(0,9) will go from 0 to 8 (doesnt include last number). Therefore, if you do len(list)-1, it wont finish at the last index, it will finish just before the last entry. Which is why 9 isn't being displayed in your results as the sequence only checks up to 8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should just directly loop through your values instead of indices

```
for i in numbers:
```

Otherwise if you wanted to use `range` you would have to index into your `list`

```
for i in range(0, len(numbers)):
    if numbers[i] % 2 != 0 :
        new_list.append(numbers[i])
```

For brevity, list comprehensions are well-suited for this type of task

```
>>> new_list = [num for num in l if num % 2 == 1]
>>> new_list
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
[k for k in l if k %2]
```

Is a simple [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) that returns

```
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this more easily with the `filter` built-in function:

```
list(filter(lambda x: x % 2, l))
```

```
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

It will only retain elements for which the condition evaluates to `True`

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are starting your range() function of your for loop from 0 and ending at len(numbers)-1 (which is 9 in your case), python range() already will run till end-1:

for eg:

```
for i in range(0,9):
    print(i)
```

will print no's:
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8

and that's why your 9 is not here in the output.

you don't have to start your loop from 0.
If you are starting from 0 you can arrange your for loop like this:

1)

```
for i in range(0, len(numbers)+1)
```

2)Or you can code like more pythonic way.

```
def remove_even(numbers) :
    new_list = []
    for i in numbers :
        if i % 2 != 0 :
            new_list.append(i)
    return new_list
```

Comment: The two methods you describe are not equivalent in the slightest.

Answer (score 0):

```
#simpliest way of doing it
mylist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
for x in mylist:
    if x % 2 == 1: #this displays odd numbers
        print(x)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

odds = [i for i in numbers if i%2!=0]
```

Answer (score -1):

def odd_numbers(n):return [x for x in range(1,n+1)  if x%2==1]print(odd_numbers(5))  # Should print [1, 3, 5]

Comment: This isn't valid python.

Answer (score -1):

```
def remove_even(numbers) :
    new_list = []
    for i in range(0,len(numbers)-1) :
        if i % 2 != 0 :
            new_list.append(i)
    return new_list 

l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] 
print(remove_even(l))
```

you got the algorithm right in the money. All you need to change is -1 to +1 instead and you will get your desired result.

why change the logic algorithm if only one item is to be changed.

Comment: Problem already answered. And iterating over the range instead of the number is not the right solution.

Answer (score -2):

It's simple using list comprehension:

```py
def odd_no(n):
      return [x for x in range(n+1) if n%2==1]
```

Comment: Doesn't work: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PyU1TSE/JSU@L18jT9OKSwEMilJLSovyFKIrFNLyixQqFDLzFIoS89JTNfK0DTUVMtMU8lSNbG0NY7m4Cooy80o0oAYYGmhqookYamr@/w8A "Python 3 – Try It Online")