# Writing a Loop to see if a number in a list is even or odd (python)

Tags: python

I am trying to write a loop that goes through a list of numbers and prints whether each number is even or odd. It seemed pretty simple, but it just infinitely prints odd. What is the fallacy?

```
samplenumber = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
o = 0
f1 = samplenumber[o]
while f1 < 11:
    if f1%2 == 0:
        print ("EVEN")
    else:
        print ("ODD")
    o += 1
```

Comment: `o` or `f1` never changes?

Comment: `f1` doesn't change inside the loop, so if `f1 < 11` initially, then it remains that way forever

Comment: Is there an increment of `o` i missed?

Comment: @billz oh sorry I forgot to copy the last line. I add 1 to ```o``` each time the loop occurs

Comment: So now you're changing `o` in each iteration -- that should be in your condition. Replace `f1` with `o` in the condition. Plus, you probably want `f1` to also change -- so you look at the next number in the list each time..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I want to return only the odd numbers in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41676212/i-want-to-return-only-the-odd-numbers-in-a-list)

Comment: This is more or less a dupe of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41676212/i-want-to-return-only-the-odd-numbers-in-a-list) post. There are some approaches there you can consider to restructure your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to read up on [for-loops](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp), friend!

```
samplenumber = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
for i in samplenumber:
     if i%2 == 0:
       print ("EVEN")
     else:
       print ("ODD")
```

best of luck, cheers.

Comment: I understand your code, but what is wrong with mine?

Comment: You're not incrementing f1. You need to add 1 to f1 at the end of every loop.

Comment: I add 1 to ```o```. This should also add 1 to f1 every time the loop is executed.

Comment: exactly, see Michele's answer below as well. Remember to mark it solved!

Answer (score 1):

You have an infinite while loop because you're incrementing the wrong variable. The while loop condition has to equal false at some point, but yours will never equal false (so it keeps running over and over again). See my comment in your code for further explanation:

```
samplenumber = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
o = 0
f1 = samplenumber[o]
while f1 < 11: #f1 will always equal 1 (samplenumber[o] = samplenumber[0] = 1), and 1 is always <11 
    if f1%2 == 0:
        print ("EVEN")
    else:
        print ("ODD")
    o += 1
```

You should either increment f1 in your while loop or use o as your counter variable.

Have a nice day!

Comment: At the end, 1 is added to o. This means that 1 is also added to f1, so it will be false at one point (when f1 and o reaches 11)

Comment: No, but f1 doesn't change. f1 doesn't ACTUALLY equal samplenumber[o], it equals whatever samplenumber[o] IS - in this case, 1 (the compiler finds what samplenumber[o] is and assigns that to f1). So when o changes, f1 doesn't automatically change. F1 would only change if you put a statement at the inside of the while loop, "f1 = samplenumber[o]" to keep reassigning new values to f1. This way f1 will be updated. Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 0):

ans:

```
    def test2():
        samplenumber = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
        for item in samplenumber:
            if item%2 == 0:
                print("EVEN")
            else:
                print("ODD")
```

Output:

```
    ODD
    EVEN
    ODD
    EVEN
    ODD
    EVEN
    ODD
    EVEN
    ODD
    EVEN
```

Comment: I understand that your method works, but what is the fallacy in mine? What makes my code infinitely loop "Odd"?

Comment: Hi , in code  given in question "f1" is outside loop, it is assigned with "samplenumber[o]", after this f1 is not modified, f1%2 , is always performed on value "1". u can move "f1 = samplenumber[o]" this inside while. in python there is already construct to refer data in array/list without using [], in loops i used the same which avoids multiple steps.